# Create a stdout and stderr files using a multiple instruction (with cicles and statements) bash script

Tags: bash, stdout, stderr

I have a bash script with several instructions like cycles and statements.

I would like to create a stdout and stderr files to print possible errors that can happen during the analysis.

However the advices in this and other forums do not work properly: in fact no file is generated despite the analysis is correctly carried out.

Here is a frame of my code:

```
#!bin/bash

{
start=`date +%s` ;
while IFS=, read -r col1 col2 ;
do
    name="$col1$col2" ; 
done < "/path/to/file.csv" ;
...
for file in ./*txt
do
    operation1
    operation2
done
} > stdout.txt 2stderr.txt

tar -zcf ./folder
```

I tried to change semicolon (;) with and (&) but did not work. Do you guys have any clues about it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give a couple lines of the CSV? When you say it doesn't work, what part doesn't work? What's the behavior you want vs what you are seeing?

Comment: The semicolons are unnecessary. `2stderr.txt` is probably going to result in a syntax error. Which files are not being created?

Answer (score 3):

You are close, presuming your `operation1` and `operation2` write the `stdout` or `stderr` depending on the result of each command, you want

```
#!/bin/bash

{
    commands

} 2>stderr.txt >stdout.txt

tar ... stuff
```

You redirect to `stderr` then to `stdout` (preferably, either order will work) ... but ***the important part is*** no spaces between the `2` and `>`.

**Trivial Working Example**

```
#!/bin/bash

{
    [ 1 -eq 1 ] && echo "good int"
    [ a -eq a ] && echo "good char"

} 2>stderr.txt >stdout.txt
```

**Results**

```
$ cat stdout.txt
good int

$ cat stderr.txt
./s.sh: line 5: [: a: integer expression expected
```